# Node Operators Reward

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, block

Why don't we implement a Node Operator reward program (in the core) or if such implementation ever existed what would be the overall (Downside,Cause for concern, etc)

Why don't we use the Miner Fee Reward to pay the Nodes for instance? Without talking about the overall economic implication but more the technical side of things.